# Solving a particular function

Tags: calculus

> Given the function
>
> $$\epsilon (k, \omega) = 1 - \frac 1 2 \left[ \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega-kv_0)^2} + \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega+kv_0)^2}\right] = 0$$
>
> Obtain $\omega(k)$ in the form $y^2=1+2\alpha^2 \pm(1+8\alpha^2)^{1/2}$, where $\alpha:= kv_0/\omega_p$ and $y:= \sqrt{2}\omega/\omega_p$
>
> Treat $k,\omega$ as variables and $v_0,\omega_p$ as constants.

I performed the following manipulations

$$\frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega-kv_0)^2} + \frac{\omega_p^2}{(\omega+kv_0)^2} = 2 \Rightarrow \omega^2\left(\frac{\omega^2+2kv_0+k^2v_0^2+\omega^2-2kv_0+k^2v_0^2}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}\right) = \frac{2}{\omega_p^2}\omega^2= y^2$$

But I do not see how to show that

$$\omega^2\left(\frac{\omega^2+2kv_0+k^2v_0^2+\omega^2-2kv_0+k^2v_0^2}{(\omega^2-k^2v_0^2)^2}\right) = 1+2\alpha^2 \pm(1+8\alpha^2)^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By dividing numerator and denominator by $\omega_p^2$, and taking the $2$ inside the parentheses, you get
$$
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}\omega/\omega_p-\sqrt{2}kv_0/\omega_p)^2}+\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2}\omega/\omega_p+\sqrt{2}kv_0/\omega_p)^2}=1
$$
The substitutions provide
$$
\frac{1}{(y-\sqrt{2}\alpha)^2}+\frac{1}{(y+\sqrt{2}\alpha)^2}=1
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{(y+\sqrt{2}\alpha)^2+(y-\sqrt{2}\alpha)^2}{(y^2-2\alpha^2)^2}=1
$$
and again
$$
\frac{2y^2+4\alpha^2}{(y^2-2\alpha^2)^2}=1
$$
Finally, solving the quadratic equation
$$
(y^2-2\alpha^2)^2=2(y^2+2\alpha^2)
$$
with respect to $y^2$ you get the result